# css - transform select option to link

Tags: css

Is it possible to display every option of a select as labels / spans?

I need to display like that, but to avoid conflicts with existing other solutions, I don't want to change the html.

Example:

```
div
    select
         item 1
         item 2
```

Expected result

```
div    
    item 1 | item 2 | item 3
```

Comment: How do you expect to use label\span without changing the HTML?

Comment: You would use Radio Buttons for that

Comment: @AlonEitan display as inline element I mean...

Answer (score 2):

You could use *escaped unicode* as css content attribute.
Add it to the option elements inside your `select` html tag.
Place this in the css:

```
option:not(:first-child):before { content:"\00a6"; }
```

This will show the character | before all the options but the first one:

```
option 1 | option 2 | option 3
```

More readings about the available unicode options [here](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/).

### Update

In order to have the option html elements in line you can do:

```
select option                          { display: inline-block; }
select option:not(:first-child):before { content:"\00a6"; }
```

Comment: I did a test over here: https://jsfiddle.net/3y04kvfz/ however it's still being displayed as a dropdown. I would like to float the options and display as inline elements. Do you think is it possible?

Comment: well. I was expecting the options outside the dropdown (somehow). Is it possible? here's a update https://jsfiddle.net/3y04kvfz/1/